# retrieving values from one table based condition on the retrieving table and reefrencing table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `tblorders` and `tblprogramme` as shown in below images.

I will select `PartyName` (from `tblorders`) from a dropdownlist in asp.net, based on that only those JobNo should come whose all the `Status` (from `tblprogramme`) is dispatched.

I want query for that.

e.g

I want "Parry's"(in table tblorders)  That "JobNo" whose all the "Status"(in tblprogramme ) is "Dispatched")

In my case from below table images

Query should return "JobNo"( 2).as Parry's this JobNo's (in tblProgramme") has status (Dispatched ib tblprogramme

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1ozV.png)).

Comment: Are you looking for just sql query?

Comment: yes..Mr.Piyush Khatri Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  t1.JobNo
FROM    tblOrders t1
WHERE   t1.PartyName = 'Parry'
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                         FROM   tblProgramme t2
                         WHERE  t1.JobNo = t2.JobNo
                                AND t2.ProgrammeStatus <> 'Dispatched' );
```

Comment: thanku for ur answer sir..

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        jobno,
        name,
        TotalCount = (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM tblProgramme
            WHERE jobno = o.jobno
        ),
        DispatchedCount = (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM tblProgramme
            WHERE jobno = o.jobno AND status = 'dispatched'
        )
    FROM tblOrder o
) t
WHERE name = 'Parry'
    AND TotalCount = DispatchedCount
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer.but i m getting all the jobno for parry.I have this query(select jobid
from tblprogramme
group by jobid
having min(ProgrammeStatus) = max(ProgrammeStatus) and min(ProgrammeStatus) = 'Dispatched';)..but i can retrieve on the basis for only jobno not those job having partyname 'Parry'.please can u help me now?

Comment: Can you please try with query which I sent?

Comment: I appreciate ur effort for helping me but i m getting all the jobno for parry.srry but not as per my requirement.i want Parry's  all the Jobno whose programmeid is having status="Dispatched".in my images ans should be "2"..

Comment: Oh, you mean you want only those job numbers which have dispatched for all rows in 2nd column. Is it correct?

Comment: yes sir.u r absolutely correct..

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: thanku so much sir,I got what i wanted...Thanku sir again.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer?

Comment: yes.but plz tell me how to accept.

Comment: You will see right icon under my answer.  Please click on that

Comment: I am doing but i think since I don't have 15 reputation that's y my vote is not acceptable. Sorry for that.

Comment: Try now... I have up voted your questions...